# React Native Webview not asking for permission but still able to access files

Tags: react-native

I have implemented webview and try to open it and there is an option where I need to upload images.

Now i freshly run my code and the Android is not asking for permissions and I am still able to get the access to the Camera and the photos access.

I tried to remove the permissions using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
```

It is not working and I am still not being prompted for the persmissions.

> <WebView
> ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
> source={{ uri: url }}
> javaScriptEnabled={true}
> domStorageEnabled={true}
> // onNavigationStateChange={this.handleWebViewNavigationStateChange}
> />

Comment: Did you recompile your code after change the native code?

Comment: Recompile by using react-native run-android?

Comment: Yes, you can use `react-native run-android` to recompile your code.

Comment: I have tried it but still. No Luck. I need to know why this is happening and does the permission is enabled by default